# How do I monitor bandwidth use of a specific website?

Tags: web, monitor, bandwidth

I would like to install an application on one computer to monitor the bandwidth used when browsing to a specific website. Is there an application that can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this for example with the Chrome dev tools. You can also monitor the response time and so on. For Chrome you can look here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: Chrome dev tools is the BOMB! It explodes with usefulness :)

Answer (score 4):

Your browser?

Most (All?) browsers these days come with built-in development tools, specifically something where you can view all network traffic including a "Total" line which will show you the amount of traffic that has been sent/received the site whilst it was loading / in use.

For example in IE > 8 (maybe 9), hit F12, click 'Network', hit 'Start Capturing' and refresh this page. At the bottom you will see 2 figures for Sent/Received data. In the actual display you'll see each individual resource's bandwidth usage and the time it took to receive the data, mostly you can drill down and see all sorts of other information related to grabbing the resource.

Answer (score 4):

IE, Chrome and Firefox all have good, built in Network and Performance monitoring tools via the F12 key. What's nice is that you can get to these tools the same way in any of these 3 browsers:

*Hit F12, click the Network tab, then the play button.*

The Performance tab is also useful.

**Internet Explorer 11**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/network

**Chrome**

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/

**Firefox**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

**Safari**

I don't have Safari handy so I can't confirm that F12 will work, but instead you hit Safari menu, then Preferences, then Advanced, then select "Show Develop menu in menu bar" then close/back out.

https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox, it is very simple.

First, load website and then press `F12`.

Click on `Network` and reload.

You will see total Data required to fully load that website in your browser.